# Oracle EXTRACT xml in PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, string-aggregation

I'm right in the middle of migration from Oracle to PostgreSQL and I have problem with something like that:

```
RTRIM(XMLAGG(XMLELEMENT(e,'WZ-'||C.docnum,'; ')
.EXTRACT('//text()') ORDER BY C.docnum).GetClobVal(),'; ') As x
```

How to convert it on PostgreSQL?
Thanks in advance

Comment: Tried with `XPATH`? https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/static/functions-xml.html

Comment: no, but a_horse_with_no_name's solution works. Thanks for fast response

Comment: great :-) a_horse_with_no_name is a legend!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I can tell this is using `XMLAGG` only because Oracle's `listag()` can't handle strings larger than 4K (or 32K in Oracle 12).

So I *think* what you want is a simple:

```
string_agg('WZ-'||c.docnum, '; ' order by c.docnum)
```

---

If `docnum` can be `NULL` you maybe want:

```
string_agg(concat('WZ-', c.docnum), '; ' order by c.docnum)
```

because `concat()` will treat `null` values as an empty string (`||` will yield `null` if any of the values involved is `null`)